# Is 'distinct' an ordinary operation for ClickHouse?

Tags: clickhouse

I would like to use ClickHouse for marketing. Most of the time they not just want to know HOW much people use some feature but the exact emails to send spam to. 
Is that a good choice to use ClickHouse for such purpose (select DISTINCT email from table where ...)? What is the difference in performance between 'select COUNT' and 'select DISTINCT'?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is that a good choice to use ClickHouse for such purpose

Yes, ClickHouse has decent HashTable and Aggregator implementations. It heavily uses templated code for static type dispatching and applies a lot of memory tricks. And it stores data in a compact form.

I assume you'd like to compare `select count` and `select count(distinct)` as `select distinct` is a different beast. ClickHouse transforms `count(distinct)` into aggregator `uniqExact` which is about 8 times slower than `count(*)`, but is still much faster than tranditional databases like Postgres. There are also approximate aggregators `uniq`, `uniqCombined` and `uniqHLL12` for faster estimations, which is around 1.5 times slower than `count(*)`. See https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/query_language/agg_functions/reference/ if you need more info.

If your goal is `select distinct`, ClickHouse can still do it well, which uses `Set` data structure to uniquify the data streams (`Set` is also used for building its SQL `in (...)` construct). Without measuring the data output process, it's only 1.3x slower than plain `count(*)`.